# Two Custom User Controls That Should Update Each Other But Only One Does (ASP.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web form in asp.net 4.5.  In this web form I have 2 user controls that I made.  Each control has complementary lists of softball players.
  Control 1 has a list of players not on a team
  Control 2 has a list of players on a selected team

Each control has an event that alerts the host page of when a change is made to the players.  When the host page event fires it will run a method on the corresponding user control to update it's player collection.

This relationship works and updates correctly when Control 1 has a change.  Control will update and display correctly on the page reload.  Strangely, when Control 2 has a change neither of the controls updates correctly.  I did check that the database is updated at the right time.  This is a side project and there is a mismatch of patterns.

Hosting Web Form:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TeamPlayerManager.OnBulkPlayersAdded += TeamPlayerManager_OnBulkPlayersAdded;
    TeamRoster.OnPlayerRemovedFromTeam += TeamRoster_OnPlayerRemovedFromTeam;

}

void TeamPlayerManager_OnBulkPlayersAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TeamRoster.LoadPlayers();
}

void TeamRoster_OnPlayerRemovedFromTeam(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TeamPlayerManager.UpdateTeamsAndPlayers();
}
```

Control 1: has list of players without a team, user can add them to a team

```
   protected void btnAddPlayersToTeam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Logic To Save changes removed for brevity

                if (OnBulkPlayersAdded != null)
                {
                    OnBulkPlayersAdded(this, e);
                }

    }

    public void UpdateTeamsAndPlayers()
    {
        rblTeams.DataBind();  // This is attached to a SQL Data source
        cblPlayersWithoutTeam.Items.Clear();  // This is attached to a SQL Data Source
        cblPlayersWithoutTeam.DataBind();
    }
```

Control 2: User can view players on a selected team, there is a remove button for each player.  I have tried a logic layer and a sql data source in the LoadPlayers method below, both have the same effect.

```
protected void gvPlayers_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        int ndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        int key = int.Parse(gvPlayers2.DataKeys[ndex].Value.ToString());

        PlayersLogic pl = new PlayersLogic();
        pl.RemovePlayerFromTeam(key))
        {
            if (OnPlayerRemovedFromTeam != null)
            {
                OnPlayerRemovedFromTeam(this, e);
            }
            LoadPlayers();
    }
}
public void LoadPlayers()
{
    //gvPlayers.DataSource = null;
    //gvPlayers.DataBind();
    //int teamId = int.Parse(ddlTeams.SelectedValue);
    //TeamLogic tl = new TeamLogic();

    //List<Team_Players> players = tl.GetPlayersOnTeam(teamId);

    //gvPlayers.DataSource = players;

    gvPlayers2.DataBind();
}
```

When Control 1: Bulk Add Players has a change - like 3 players added to Team Black.  If Team Black is the selected team in Control 2 they will update correctly.  However, if I remove a player from a team with Control 2, neither list updates unless I do a page refresh.

Everything is wrapped in a Master page which has the entire host page in a single Ajax Update Panel.  I'm simply stumped at why the update works fine in one direction and not the other.  My best guess is something different between a radio button list and a grid view...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer which worked for me [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1627583.aspx?Gridview%20not%20refreshing%20after%20deleting%20record).  Basically I changed my code a little by adding a RowDeleting event.  I moved my custom event being raised there and also the code to rebind the grid view there as well.  Everything worked.

```
protected void gvPlayers_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        int ndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        int key = int.Parse(gvPlayers2.DataKeys[ndex].Value.ToString());

        PlayersLogic pl = new PlayersLogic();
        pl.RemovePlayerFromTeam(key);
    }
}


protected void gvPlayers2_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

    if (OnPlayerRemovedFromTeam != null)
    {
        OnPlayerRemovedFromTeam(this, e);
    }

    LoadPlayers(true);
}
```